# Set a default font family and size in ckeditor

Tags: wysiwyg

Its been 4 days I am trying to set a default font family to the ckeditor(not set default label) but I am not able to do the task. Also i tried working with content.css but its not working. Please need a help

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using the CKEditor module you will need to override it using CSS. You can either create a ckeditor.css file to override it or edit it in your theme file.

Or you can add

```
config.extraCss += "body{font-family:Arial, serif;}";
```

To your extra javascript section in the settings text format.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you.

In Drupal 7, go to the configuration options of CKEditor in your admin area (admin/config/content/ckeditor) press the "edit" button for the profile that you want to add this option to, and add the code in the "Advanced Options" -> "Custom JavaScript configuration".

```
    config.font_names =
            'Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;' +
            'Times New Roman/Times New Roman, Times, serif;' +
            'Verdana';
```

**You can also achieve it by**

- Let say **Verdana** be the default font

  - Open **contents.css** file and change the font to

    ```
    font-family: Verdana;
    ```
  - In the **application/page** where the output will be published, add this style

    ```
    <style> .entry-content {font-family: Tahoma;} </style>
    ```

[CKEditor offical document](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.font_names)

Comment: The way you did it just gives the names of font family on the font scroller. What I am trying to do is when someone tries to start typing in the ckeditor the Font family should be set as Arial with default. Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: @bashres that' what i want, I want the font that is being typed to be my selected font.

Answer (score 0):

Add below lines in CKEditor `config.js` or your own `custom.js` where you configure the CKEditor options.

```
config.font_defaultLabel = 'Arial';
config.fontSize_defaultLabel = '16px';
```

Answer (score 0):

You've to do 3 steps of work to set the CK Editor default Font family & Size.

Edit your content.css in the CKEditor folder

1. Change the Font-family & font-size as per your need in Body → This will set your default font family

   ```
   body
   {   
   font-family:Georgia;
   }
   ```
2. Change the same font-size as per your need in .cke_editable → This
   will set your default font-size in the Editor

   ```
   .cke_editable
   {
   font-size: 18px;
   }
   ```

`3. Go to Your CKEditor → Update your CKEditor Dropdown config settings

```
        using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

            @Html.TextArea("ContentEditor", CurrentItem.Content)
            <script>
            CKEDITOR.replace('ContentEditor');
            CKEDITOR.config.font_defaultLabel = 'Georgia';
            CKEDITOR.config.fontSize_defaultLabel = '20';
            </script>

        }
```

Hopes this will Help...